# variable string appearing as undefined, new string not appearing in array, javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, iteration

I'm attempting to write some code that puts a single string of emails into an array of emails.   Splitting the string wherever there's a comma(,). The initial problem i'm having is the string that is being passed as a variable is not being recognized. I'm getting the error message "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" of the conditional part of the `for` loop. Odd, as I'm definitely passing a string or trying to ?

When I pass in a string directly to the function parameter(to avoid the above problem for testing the rest of the function) only the first 2 email addresses appear the final email address is lost ?

I'm learning programming and this is an exercise as such I'm trying to avoid using the `split()` method or regEx. Daft i know.

Any help in overcoming these 2 issues greatly appreciated.

```
function separateCommaValues(text)
{

    var input = [];
    var val = '';

    for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++)     {
        if(text[i] == ',') {
            if(val.length == 0){
                continue;
            }
                input.push(val);
                val = '';

        } else {
                 val += text[i];
        }
    }
    document.write( input );
}

separateCommaValues(str);

var str = "john@google.com, jake@yahoo.com, andrew@hotmail.com";
```

Comment: You should define the variable before using it. Move the `var str = "...";` line before the call to `separateCommaValues(str);`

Comment: shouldn't str be initialized before its used?

Comment: If this isn't an academic exercise, I recommend using String.split: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: First thing I notice is that your function appears to require a comma before pushing the text to the array.  Since there is no comma after the third email address, it won't get pushed in.

Comment: Long way to change a string into an array.

Comment: As a side note, you probably also want your scanner to ignore spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "john@google.com, jake@yahoo.com, andrew@hotmail.com"; 

separateCommaValues(str);
```

This is the correct order. Your variable can be declared before it is used via hoisting, but you can't define it before it is used (undefined error).

Answer (score 0):

And the last email address isn't pushed into the array because it doesn't have a comma after it. So after the loop, before `document.write( input );`, add something like this:

```
if(val.length > 0){
  input.push(val);
  val = '';
}
```